# I have an issue calling pow function (c standard function ) from assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, calling-convention, pow

my code looks like so :

```
extern pow
global main 
section .text 


main :



sub rsp , 8
movss xmm0 , [_1.2]
movss xmm1 , [_2.3] 
call pow
mov [result ] , rax

add rsp , 8
ret 

section .data 

_1.2 : dq 4.0 
_2.3 : dq 0.5
result : dq 0.0
```

i compile and run using : nasm -fwin64 a.asm && gcc a.obj && a

i dont get any errors but the value of the rax register after the call does not match the result. i ve tried to use rcx and rdx registers for passing the values , but same . im using x64dbg ...

Comment: Floating point numbers are returned in `xmm0`, not `rax`.  Refer to the amd64 SysV ABI supplement for details.

Comment: Or to MS docs for Windows x64, if you're using that calling convention (which is normal for targets that use `-fwin64`)

Comment: Also, you know the CPU has `pow(x, 0.5)` built in, right?  `sqrtpd xmm0, [rel _1.2]`.  Also, wait a minute, you're using `movss` 32-bit (Single-precision) loads from 64-bit (Double-precision `dq`) constants, so you're calling `pow(0.0, 0.0)` because those nice round numbers (powers of 2) have a mantissa of all-zeros.

Comment: ok, everything worked fine , thanks!! i was looking at the wrong register for the result

Comment: What's with the weird edit? Why did you completely change a 4 month old question so that the existing comments no longer make any sense? If you have a new question, post it as a separate question.

Comment: I can only edit existing questions . Probably not that good idea i guess ...